# How to send text from textarea to a file

Tags: php, html

I want to know how to make user enter some text inside a textarea then when he press the save button the text that he typed get saved inside a file here is my code :

```
<?php
header("location: add/Project.html" );

 $handle = fopen("Project.html", "a");
 foreach($_POST as $value) {

 fwrite($handle, $value);
 }
 fclose($handle);
exit;
?>
```

This code works but with the `<input>` only for example here is my html Code :

```
<form action="add.php" method="post">
<textarea type="text" name="code" id="code" value="" ></textarea>
<input type="text" name="code" id="code" value="" /><input value="Submit" tabindex="4"   type="submit" >
 </form>
```

It will output only the text that was written in the `<input>`
Can you help me please !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `textarea` and `input` have the same name. To fix, give them different names:

```
<form action="add.php" method="post">
    <textarea type="text" name="codetextarea" id="codetextarea" value="" ></textarea>
    <input type="text" name="codeinput" id="codeinput" value="" />
    <input value="Submit" tabindex="4"   type="submit" />
 </form>
```

(They also have identical `id`s, which is even illegal in XHTML)

Comment: It is not stupid; we all make obvious mistakes, even after many years.

Answer (score 0):

If you have inputs with the same name (and that name doesn't end in `[]`), then PHP will ignore all but one of them (as far as I can tell, this makes it unique among form processing libraries). Give them different names.

Alternatively, rename them to `code[]` and PHP will populate `$_POST['code']` with an array. Then loop over *that* array instead of `$_POST` itself.

Answer (score -1):

The two answers above mine have the point. Also, you don't need `value` attribute in `<textarea>`, because textarea's value comes from whatever is within opened and closed `<textarea></textarea>` tags. It is different than for `<input>` tags.

Also, when opening a file, you should specify another 'reading' property called binary ( a letter b ).

So it should look like

```
$handle = fopen('path_to_file.extension','ab');
```

This is for compatibility purpose

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<form action="add.php" method="post">
<textarea  name="codetextarea" id="codetextarea" value="" ></textarea>
<input type="text" name="codeinput" id="codeinput" value="" />
<input value="Submit" tabindex="4"   type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: did u try that ? because by default input type in a form is text , and your text area syntax force it to become text and your value part="". So there will not any data